# Why does the cxf-codegen maven plugin fail to run the wsdl2java goal on OpenJDK 10?

Tags: java, cxf-codegen-plugin

The following plugin invocation keeps failing:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/emailIRN.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
... more wsdlOption blocks...
```

There are two warnings:

```
 [WARNING] Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.ForkOnceWSDL2Java
 [WARNING] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.ForkOnceWSDL2Java
```

Then the whole thing fails with:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --add-exports=jdk.xml.dom/org.w3c.dom.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED -jar /tmp/cxf-tmp-975998357168064227/cxf-codegen15218503234725715130.jar /tmp/cxf-tmp-975998357168064227/cxf-w2j6542191939703642136args
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I realized that the issue with that with OpenJDK 10, the JEE API is not defined.  This is causing the plugin to fail silently (regardless of what debugging options are given).

I also changed the plugin to an older version, as the newer one does not seem to be satisfied with the JEE 7 API.

```
                <version>3.2.0</version>
```

I was able to resolve this by adding the `javaee-api` dependency as follows:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/emailIRN.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
    ... more wsldOption blocks ...
```